# vscode: c/c++ extension: run code not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

In VSCode (Visual Studio Code) I can "Debug C/C++ File" and I can "Run C/C++ File", but I get a compiler error when I "Run Code" because the compiler can't file the include directory.

```
[Running] cd "c:\Repo\C++\unit test\files\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Repo\C++\unit test\files\"main
main.cpp:4:10: fatal error: include\files.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include "include\files.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have the include directory in the tasks.json file under args "-IC:\Repo\C++"

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-IC:\\Repo\\C++"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include "include\files.h"

void test_example() { // Code}

void test_files() { // Code}


int main()
{
    test_example();
    test_files();
    
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas on how I modify the tasks.json or a different XXX.json file to include the directory.  I am just trying to understand all the details of why it works 2 out of the 3 ways and what I have to do to get it to work for all three ways.  I have read thru online documentation, but it is always at a high level that the fine details are left out.

Comment: what is the contents of `C:\\Repo\\C++`? Please show a [mre]

Comment: I recommend against using code runner. `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json` are used when code-runner is not being used. code-runner has a completely different json file to edit.

Comment: The content of C:\Repo\C++\include is just the "include" folder.  The include folder has the "files.h" in it.

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example.  What is the JSON for code runner?  From the compiler error it looks like I am missing the command line args for the compiler to find the included files.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the settings JSON to see if this would do anything.  It does change the compiler error slightly... But, it is basically the same compiler error...

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {

        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && -I C:\\Repo\\C++ && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "cpp": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && -I C:\\Repo\\C++ && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
    },

main.cpp:4:10: fatal error: include\files.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include "include\files.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: You are still getting the same include error, 'files.h' is still not being found by the compiler.  And it seems like you are trying to mix debugging and running with code runner. Debugger is provided by the Language extension which uses tasks.json and gdb to debug while code runner just executes a command to compile and run the program. If your project is more complex than 2-3 files in a single directory, you should consider using a makefile (a simple build automation system). It is very easy to write a make file for a simple project.

Comment: Are you saying there is no solution to this issue by modifying the JSON files?  And that to correct this issue would require a makefile.  If yes, then to use "code runner" and to include a header in a different directory would require a makefile.  Or is "code runner" the issue.

Comment: Could you explain how you are running the program exactly? 

There is a solution to this issue by modifying json file, but if your purpose is not debugging, I am not sure the tasks.json affects code runner. Code runner is a simple extension that can execute a single command and provides you with some variables like file name and directory names. Tasks.json is not this simple, it is essentially a recipe where you can include variables like compiler location, include paths etc, which is then used to generate a command to compile and run the resulting binary.

Comment: It would also be good if you can share a minimal project directory as a zip because the structure of your directories isn't really evident in the question.